CORS issue when integrating SignalR with Angular 10 and .NET Framework 4.6.1
I'm facing a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue while trying to integrate SignalR with Angular 10 and a .NET Framework 4.6.1 project. I've followed the typical setup steps but seem to be encountering CORS-related errors.
In my .NET project, I have to implement a SignalR hub (ChatHub) with the following configuration:
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[HubName("Chat")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }
}

Additionally, I've set up the OWIN startup class (Startup.cs) as follows:
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YourNamespace.Startup))]

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<CorsOptions> SignalrCorsOptions = new Lazy<CorsOptions>(() =>
        {
            return new CorsOptions
            {
                PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
                {
                    PolicyResolver = context =>
                    {
                        var policy = new CorsPolicy();
                        policy.AllowAnyOrigin = true;
                        policy.AllowAnyMethod = true;
                        policy.AllowAnyHeader = true;
                        policy.SupportsCredentials = false;
                        return Task.FromResult(policy);
                    }
                }
            };
        });

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(SignalrCorsOptions.Value);
                map.RunSignalR(new HubConfiguration());
            });

            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
}


On the Angular side, I'm using the @microsoft/signalr package. Here's a snippet from my Angular service:
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {
  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;

  constructor() {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('http://localhost:44300/signalr/chat')
      .build();

    this.hubConnection.start()
      .then(() => console.log('SignalR connection started.'))
      .catch(err => console.error('Error while starting SignalR connection: ' + err));
  }

  public sendMessage(name: string, message: string): void {
    this.hubConnection.invoke('Send', name, message)
      .catch(err => console.error('Error while sending message: ' + err));
  }

  public receiveMessage(callback: (name: string, message: string) => void): void {
    this.hubConnection.on('broadcastMessage', callback);
  }
}



Despite these configurations, I'm consistently encountering the following CORS error:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:44300/signalr/chat/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


I suspect that I might not be using the SignalR path (http://localhost:44300/signalr/chat) correctly or missing some crucial configuration. Can someone please guide me on resolving this CORS issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Why 4.6.1? It's out of support. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2. SignalR was rebuilt for .NET Core by the way to fix a lot of the issues of the .NET Framework version and remove some of the techniques that were no longer useful once all browsers offered WebSockets. The .NET Framework version is in maintenance mode.

For new projects, especially SPAs, it's a lot better to use ASP.NET Core. Check Tutorial: Create an ASP.NET Core app with Angular in Visual Studio

We have an existing project in .NET 4.6.1, which is a large project currently in production. Therefore, we cannot change the version of the project

You can't NOT upgrade to 4.6.2, because 4.6.1 is unsupported and quite possibly not even the actual runtime you're using. Unsupported means no fixes any more, not even security patches. No  supported Windows version comes with 4.6.1 any more and you can't downgrade, which means you're most likely already running on 4.6.2 or later. 4.x runtime upgrades are binary replacements which means a Windows update could have upgraded the runtime already

To put it another way, if anything goes wrong due to an unpatched vulnerability on that obsolete runtime, your company (and its developers) are fully liable.

I am considering enhancing our existing solution, which is based on the 4.6.1 project, by adding a separate .NET Core 7 project for SignalR implementation. This project will function independently.
